# How to pass data from Activity A to fragment in Activity B?

Tags: java, android

I need to pass data from Activity "MainCalendar" to fragment "AddTaskFragment" in Activity "Add". I have a button in a fragment which opens an Activity "MainCalendar", where I select a date in the calendar, and then I need to send this date into a fragment.

When I click on Choose Button, there is opens a MainCalendar, where user need to choose date, after that, the activity closed, and than I want to put a date from MainCalendar to the text of "Choose Button".

[Add Activity with a fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtUzi.png),
MainCalendar Activity:[MainCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln7k2.png)

MainCalendar.class:

```
public class MainCalendar extends AppCompatActivity {
private CalendarView Calendar;
private String date;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_calendar);
    Calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);



    Calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            date = (dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            System.out.println(date);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainCalendar.this, Add.class);
            intent.putExtra("DATE_KEY", date);
            finish();
        }

    });
}
```

Add.class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.add);
    Button notes_button = findViewById(R.id.notes_btn);
    Button tasks_button = findViewById(R.id.tasks_btn);
    Button goals_button = findViewById(R.id.goals_btn);
    RadioButton rb = findViewById(R.id.choose_day_btn);


    String date = null;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
        date = extras.getString("DATE_KEY");
    }

    AddTasksFragment frag = new AddTasksFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("DATE_KEY", date);
    frag.setArguments(bundle);

    Fragment fragment1 = new AddTasksFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment1).commit();


    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.notes:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notes.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.add:
                    return true;
                case R.id.tasks:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tasks.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.goals:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Goals.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.statistics:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Statistics.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Fragment fragment = new AddTasksFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();

    tasks_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new AddTasksFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    notes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new AddNotesFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    goals_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new AddGoalsFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

//

AddTaskFragment.class, which is in Add.class:

```
  @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_tasks_fragment, container, false);

    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    subtask_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_subtask_btn);
    subtask_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.subtask_name);
    task_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    lin_lay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    sb_lay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.subtask_lay);
    apply_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.apply_btn);

    rgDay = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.date_group);
    rgPriority = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.priority_group);
    todayBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.today_btn);
    tomorrowBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tomorrow_btn);
    chooseDayBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choose_day_btn);
    lowPrBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.low_btn);
    mediumPrBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.medium_btn);
    highPrBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.high_btn);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(TASKS_KEY);
    this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();


    subtask_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    apply_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            writeTask();
        }
    });
    chooseDayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainCalendar.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    String data;
    data = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(DATE_KEY);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    addView();
}



private void writeTask() {
    String Task;
    Task = task_name.getText().toString();
    dataBase.push().setValue(Task);

    String[] subTasks = new String[sb_lay.getChildCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < sb_lay.getChildCount(); i++) {

        View subtaskView = sb_lay.getChildAt(i);

        EditText editTextName = (EditText) subtaskView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_name);
        subTasks[i] = editTextName.getText().toString();

        dataBase.child(Task).child("Subtasks").push().setValue(subTasks[i]);
        }
        dataBase.child(Task).push().setValue(getDay());
}

private String getDay(){
    String day=null;

    if(todayBtn.isChecked()){
        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        day = currentTime.toString();
    }
    else if(tomorrowBtn.isChecked()){
        Date dt = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dt);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dt = c.getTime();
        day = dt.toString();
    }else if(chooseDayBtn.isChecked()) {
        day =  getArguments().getString("DATE_KEY");
        System.out.println(" Date is choosed ----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + day);
        chooseDayBtn.setText(day);
    }
    return day;
}

private void addView(){
    final View subtaskView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.subtask_raw, null, false);

    EditText editText = (EditText)subtaskView.findViewById(R.id.subtask_name);
    ImageView imageClose = (ImageView)subtaskView.findViewById(R.id.remove_subtask);

    imageClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeView(subtaskView);
        }
    });

    sb_lay.addView(subtaskView);
    String day;
    day =  getArguments().getString("DATE_KEY");
    System.out.println(" Date is choosed " + day);

}

private void removeView(View view){
    sb_lay.removeView(view);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: The best way would be to use intents.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you Have to activities (`Activity A` and `Activity B`) and you have a fragment in Activity B. What you want to do is sending some data from activity A to that fragment for whatever reason.

Let's have a note first, You can't directly send data to any fragment of activity without launching it. So in order to send this data to the fragment you have to pass it from `Activity A` to `Activity B` as a first step and then send it from `Activity B` to the `Fragment` as a second step.

The type of data is very important. If you are sending a custom type (a model java class) you have to define it as [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) or if it is a primitive type such as `int` or `float` so you can send it directly

this is how to do it in Java

ActivityA.java

```java
class ActivityA extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activityA);

        // define your data here
        int data = 5;

        // define an intent to send the data to the second activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("DATA_KEY", data);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Then what we need to do is

- receiving the data in the `Activity B`
- Inflating the fragment
- pass the data to the fragment

```java
class ActivityB extends Activity{


    Int data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activityB);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
            data = extras.getInt("DATA_KEY");
        }

        // Fragment instance
        FragmentClass frag = new FragmentClass();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("DATA_KEY", data );
        frag.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFeedFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        

    }
}
```

and then receive it the same way we received it in the `Activity B`